# How to pass a List<int> to a service reference (C#, VS2008)

Tags: c#, web-services

The problem i'm having is that i've created a web service, and a windows form (separate solutions).  I added the web service to the form app using a service reference, I can pass an 'int' or a 'string' to the web service no problem, but i cannot pass an array of int's or List`<int`>

The web service code is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace CalculateService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public int CalcluateSum(List<int> listInt)
        {
            int sum = listInt.Sum();
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

and the client code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CalculateForm
{
    public partial class FormCalculate : Form
    {
        List<int> intArray = new List<int>();

        public FormCalculate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAddNum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            intArray.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txtAddNum.Text));
            txtAddNum.Clear();
            listBoxAddNum.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < intArray.Count; i++)
            {
                listBoxAddNum.Items.Add(intArray[i]);
            }
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalculateForm.CalculateService.Service1SoapClient client = new CalculateForm.CalculateService.Service1SoapClient();
            int result = client.CalcluateSum(intArray);
            txtResult.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is:

> Argument '1': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'CalculateForm.CalculateService.ArrayOfInt'

I am sure it's something simple and I'll feel daft when someone points it out :)

Cheers
Carl

Comment: I would just change my web method :-) To int[]. This probably will make the life of other web service consumers easier.

Comment: I would love to but as it's for coursework they specify that:

Create a new aspx SOAP Web Service (as discussed in unit 1) that will calculate the sum of a List<int> of integers and return the result.


I don't know though if it would be possible to pass it as 'int[]' to the web service, then convert to a 'List<int>' to perform the sum, then return an 'int', thus keeping with the specification?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it working!! :)

I managed to get it to pass the **`List<int>`** rather than using the **`ToArray()`** method.

Here's the client code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CalculateForm
{
    public partial class FormCalculate : Form
    {
        List<int> listInt = new List<int>();

        public FormCalculate()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAddNum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listInt.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txtAddNum.Text));
            txtAddNum.Clear();
            listBoxAddNum.Items.Clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < listInt.Count; i++)
            {
                listBoxAddNum.Items.Add(listInt[i]);
            }
        }

        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalculateService.Service1SoapClient client = new CalculateService.Service1SoapClient();

            CalculateService.ArrayOfInt arrayOfInt = new CalculateService.ArrayOfInt();

            arrayOfInt.AddRange(listInt);

            int result = client.CalcluateSum(arrayOfInt);

            txtResult.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
        }
    }
}
```

and the web service code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace CalculateService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]

    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public int CalcluateSum(List<int> listInt)
        {
            int sum = listInt.Sum();
            return sum;
        }
    }
}
```

so basically all I had to do was create a new instance of the `CalculateService.ArrayOfInt` in the client, and add the range of data from the `List<int> listInt` then pass `arrayOfInt` to the web service.

Cheers everyone for your help, no doubt I'll be back soon :)

Answer (score 9):

WSDL cannot handle Lists, so it uses an Array instead, doing the conversion before it passes it into your Service Method.  Just call ToArray() on your List before calling the method.

Comment: You are my hero dude..i spent 6 hours today working on passing a list as a parameter to a webservice webmethod and there you go...Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

I did it using WCE3.0 extension. When you generate the `reference.cs` file, the system puts `int[]` instead of `List<int>`. You have to replace `int[]` by `List<int>` in `reference.cs` file.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 client.CalcluateSum(intArray.ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

This question looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334695/converting-generic-list-to-arrayofint-for-transmission-over-soap-to-web-service). I'd say you'd need to write a quick static function that takes in a List and performs a type conversion over to CalculateForm.CalculateService.ArrayOfInt. Your web service has generated this type, and it would seem it expects nothing less. I'm unfamiliar with this behavior because I pass Lists across web services regularly and my web services have always managed to perform the conversion .ToArray() for me.

Comment: I tried adding the web service to my client app as a 'Web Service' rather than a 'Service Reference' and this allowed me to pass the List just fine, problem being is that it's for coursework and I believe that it has to be added as a 'Service Reference'

I'll try the suggestion from the other question and see how i get on

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with for mine. It wouldn't let me cast or try all sorts of stuff. Creating and inserting separately worked fine though.

```
public static void SetStores(List<int> stores, int updateNumber)
{
    ArrayOfInt storeArray = new ArrayOfInt();
    storeArray.AddRange(stores);
    WebServiceSoapClient client = GetClient();
    bool isSuccess = client.SetStores(storeArray, updateNumber);
}
```